# Automatically quit .NET app on "unhandled exception has occurred"

Tags: .net, windows-10, nssm

I have the misfortune of being forced to run an application I didn't write as a service. The app was not designed to be run as a service so I am using NSSM. Everything is working very well except for the fact that it sometimes pops up a window saying:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the  application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the  application will close immediately.

Unfortunately this stops NSSM from restarting it, because the process hasn't actually died. How can I get .NET to let the thing die and not prompt me?

**NOTE:** I have access to neither the source code, nor Visual Studio. This is strictly a DevOps task.